# Spivak's proof of existence of partitions of unity

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

I don't understand why the highlighted statement is true. Namely, why $\varphi(x) = 0\ $ for $\varphi \in \Phi_{j},\ j\ge i+2$

[image]

The full proof can be found, for example, in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/475060/partition-of-unity-in-spivaks-calculus-on-manifolds). There's also an attempt to answer my question in the comments, but I don't see why such $C^{\infty}$ function that is somehow defined on $A$ and $0$ outside $int(A_{i+1})−A_{i−2}$ exists.

Comment: What does partition of unity *subordinate to the collection $\{\mathcal O_i\}$* entail? And note the $j\ge i+2$. Why is that essential?

Comment: @TedShifrin Well, that must imply that $\varphi = 0$ outside of some closed set $S$ contained in an element of $\{\mathcal O_i\}$. Since $x \in A_i$ and due to $j\ge i+2$ no element of $\{\mathcal O_i\}$ can contain something from $A_i$, x has to be outside of that closed set, namely, in $S^c$, which is open. THANK YOU

Comment: @Sgg8 Then you should answer your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that the partition of unity is subordinate to the cover implies that $φ=0$ outside of some closed set $S$ contained in an element of $\{Oi\}$. Since $x∈A_i$ and due to $j≥i+2$ no element of $\{Oi\}$ can contain something from $A_i$, $x$ has to be outside of that closed set, namely, in $S^c$, which is open